# Images lagging when i scroll how to fix that?

Tags: java, android, xml

I have created an app with android studio in tab1 Relative Layout I have 8 images but when I run my app and scroll it lags how to fix lagging when I scroll.

Here is the code

```
package com.example.drh3cker.ihebski_swip;


import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

//this project developped by iheb ben salem@IBSSoft
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

ViewPager pager;
PagerTabStrip tab_strp;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_tab);
    ma_pager_adapter mapager=new ma_pager_adapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    pager=(ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);

    pager.setAdapter(mapager);
    tab_strp=(PagerTabStrip)findViewById(R.id.tab_strip);
    tab_strp.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
 //   tab_strp.setTextSize(14,14);
   // tab_strp.setTabIndicatorColor(Color.WHITE);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.share) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


public void browser1(View view) {
    Intent browserIntent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://example.com"));
    startActivity(browserIntent);
```

and

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:weightSum="1">

<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:src="@drawable/fra"
        android:background="#f44437"
        android:contentDescription="@string/App_Title_Image" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:src="@drawable/saavnmusicapp"
        android:paddingTop="8sp"
        android:onClick="browser1"
        android:contentDescription="@string/saavn_music_app"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        style="?android:borderlessButtonStyle"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:src="@drawable/earntalktime"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/earn_talktime_image"
        android:onClick="browser2"
        style="?android:borderlessButtonStyle"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:src="@drawable/flipkart"
        android:onClick="browser3"
        android:contentDescription="@string/flipkart_app_image"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        style="?android:borderlessButtonStyle"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/paytmapp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/paytm_app_image"
        android:onClick="browser4"
        style="?android:borderlessButtonStyle"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView6"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/uc"
        android:onClick="browser5"
        style="?android:borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:contentDescription="@string/uc_browser_image" />

    <ImageView
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="150dp"
         android:id="@+id/imageView7"
         android:layout_below="@+id/imageView6"
         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
         android:src="@drawable/dailyhunt"
         android:onClick="browser6"
         style="?android:borderlessButtonStyle"
         android:contentDescription="@string/uc_browser_image" />

    <ImageView
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="150dp"
         android:id="@+id/imageView8"
         android:layout_below="@+id/imageView7"
         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
         android:src="@drawable/freepaisa"
         android:onClick="browser7"
         style="?android:borderlessButtonStyle"
         android:contentDescription="@string/uc_browser_image" />

    <ImageView
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="150dp"
         android:id="@+id/imageView9"
         android:layout_below="@+id/imageView8"
         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
         android:src="@drawable/mobikwik"
         android:onClick="browser8"
         style="?android:borderlessButtonStyle"
         android:contentDescription="@string/uc_browser_image" />




</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Stackoverflow is telling me to add more details I don't know why I have added the problem and the code and I want to know how can I fix that can anyone help me

Thanks.

Comment: @SarthakMittal he says that the scroller lags. the images gets loaded before he start scrolling. I don't think the problem is in images memory size. caching libraries won't solve the problem.

Comment: @hasan83 sorry, my bad, i thought the OP had used a listview

Answer (score 2):

When loading an image in an ImageView use

> ```
> imageview.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getContext().getResources(), R.drawable.image);
> ```

than

> ```
> imageview.setImageResource(R.drawable.image);
> ```

For my experience, it has lessen the Java and Graphics' memory consumption by up to 89% which makes the application run smoother and use less memory and by this, do less garbage collection as your application runs.

Next, set a constraint on the file sizes of your images to ensure highest performance possible

> From:      image.jpg    |    1.2MB
>
> To:          image.jpg    |    512KB

When the file is already in your resources folder, you can, in Mac, "reveal in Finder" or in Windows, "Open in Explorer", to show your files then you can...

- Resize the image in Preview for Mac
- Resize the image size or resize the file size of the image in Windows using Microsoft Office Picture Manager (still helps even nowadays)

Lastly, maybe you can find this article helpful for your problem

> https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-we-reduced-memory-footprint-by-50-in-our-android-app-49efa5c93ad8

Answer (score 1):

A better option would be to use a Listview or even better a RecyclerView in place of many images in a ScrollView, because they recycle items that are not seen, and in that way giving performance boost. + Picasso (image processing and caching). https://github.com/square/picasso

Here is a example for implementation: https://futurestud.io/blog/picasso-adapter-use-for-listview-gridview-etc/

Code samples from Picasso GitHub:
https://github.com/square/picasso/tree/master/picasso-sample/src/main/java/com/example/picasso

But there are many good resources for implementation, just google - android ListView or Recycler view implementation.

If you still want to use ScrollView you could replace the RelativeLayout with a Linearlayout, that could give a small performance boost, because RelativeLayout is measured 2 times.

Comment: he says that the scroller lags. the images gets loaded before he start scrolling. I don't think the problem is in images memory size is the only problem here. caching libraries won't solve the problem alone. but the caching library with a recycler view may solve the problem.

Comment: +one for covering all possible well none suggestions